# Service Bus for Windows server - slow subscriptions with a large number of filters (100+)

Tags: c#, .net, servicebus

I have a set of classes to be subscribed to messages from service bus topic. All of that classes wants to receive only certain message types, for example:

```
public class MySubscriber : IBusSubscriber, IConsume<ItemCreated>, IConsume<ItemUpdated> {
  public void Consume(ItemCreated message) { /* processing */ }
  public void Consume(ItemUpdated message) { /* processing */ }
}
```

For each of subscriber classes I create subscription with set of rules to filter messages. To MySubscriber it would be subscription named MySubscriber and two rules with SqlFilters inside:

```
"MessageType = 'ItemCreated'"
"MessageType = 'ItemUpdated'"
```

I fill MessageType as message property on publishing and it's working fine. But if amount of such rules became to growth (for example one of report subscribers require about 130 rules) it becomes **very** slow. Even without lots of messages, only one such report subscriber receives only about 1 message per second.

Can it be speed up somehow? Or maybe there is another way to implement it that avoids creating so many filters?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Service Bus would be a better choice.
If you are in ***Standard*** messaging tier consider creating your Topics as one of the below for improved performance,

1) **Express Topics** for high throughput and reduced latency scenarios

```
TopicDescription td = new TopicDescription(TopicName);
td.EnableExpress = true;
namespaceManager.CreateTopic(td);
```

2) **Partitioned Topics** higher throughput than regular queues and topics and superior availability

```
TopicDescription td = new TopicDescription(TopicName);
td.EnablePartitioning = true;
namespaceManager.CreateTopic(td);
```

However The ***Premium*** tier of Service Bus Messaging addresses common customer requests around scale, performance, and availability for mission-critical applications. The Premium tier is recommended for production scenarios.

Comment: Hi! It looks like you're talking about wrong service bus. Afaik standalone service bus does not have "tiers" and looks like you're talking about an Azure's one.

Comment: @AntonZ, Thanks for pointing this out. You are right have mentioned about Azure ServiceBus